# What is an artist of horror called?

Tags: single-word-requests

An artist of comedy is a *comedian* (like [Aristophanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristophanes)), and an artist of tragedy is a *tragedian* (like [Euripedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euripides)). What is an artist of horror called?

Comment: I think your question is based on a fundamental misunderstanding.  A comedian is someone who *performs* comedy, not someone who writes it.  Your linked Wikipedia article correctly describes Aristophanes as a "comic playwright" and not a comedian.  The word "tragedian" is certainly used to describe people who write tragedies, but to generalise from that single example that there should be single-word names for writers in every other genre does not follow.  It certainly isn't true for comedy, as one counter-example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not recognized in mainstream dictionaries, but a word that some people use is **horrormeister**.

I would not normally provide a reference to [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horrormeister), but I will in this case:

> **horrormeister** (*plural* **horrormeisters**)
> (*informal*) A person renowned for producing works in the horror genre.
> **2009** April 24, Peter Howell, “Things that go bump on the Croisette”, in *Toronto Star‎*:
>
> > Also out of competition, and screening in the midnight section, is *Drag Me to Hell* by U.S. **horrormeister** Sam Raimi, who took a break from *Spider-Man* to return to his ghastly roots with a chiller about a loans officer (Alison Lohman) condemned by a satanic curse after she denies a mortgage extension to an elderly woman.

It's formed from the words *horror* and [*meister*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meister):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : one who is knowledgeable about something specified
> —often used in combination
> // puzzle-*meister*

So, it's not without syntactic precedence to form such a word, and it does have informal use.

---

In the following references, the emphasis on the word is my own, while any other emphasis is in the referenced material itself.

From [Bunshinsaba: Ouija Board](https://variety.com/2004/film/reviews/bunshinsaba-ouija-board-1200531806/) by Derek Elley (2004):

> Highly awaited third feature by young **horrormeister** Ahn Byeong-gi, "Bunshinsaba" is a bust. "Bunshinsaba" lacks the chilling formalism of Ahn's "Phone" and instead plays like the more hysterical sections of his debut, "A Nightmare."

From ['Scream' Producer Sues Ex-Boyfriend for Stalking Her](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/thr-esq/scream-producer-sues-boyfriend-stalking-582246) by Eriq Gardner (2013)

> Maddalena is a longtime partner of **horrormeister** **Wes Craven** and has been a producer on such films as the *Scream* series, *Dracula 2000* and *The Hills Have Eyes*.

From [The 10 Best Plane Movies of All Time](https://www.popularmechanics.com/culture/movies/g3223/best-plane-movies/) by Tim Griersen (2017):

> 9. Red Eye
> **Horrormeister** Wes Craven shifted gears for this close-quarters thriller that takes its main character's fear of flying to scary new heights.

From ['Hellraiser' Reboot in the Works With David S. Goyer to Write](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/hellraiser-reboot-works-writer-david-s-goyer-1207685) by Etan Vlessing (2019):

> David S. Goyer is set to write and produce Spyglass Media Group's re-imagining of *Hellraiser*, one of **horrormeister** Clive Barker's best-known creations.

The horror author Jason Gehlert describes himself as a *horrormeister* at [his own website](https://jasongehlert.com/) and in his biographical summary page:

> **HORRORMEISTER**
> Jason Gehlert
> As **horrormeister** Jason Gehlert’s library continues to evolve and expand towards new genres, his emergence as a literary voice continues to build momentum.

Answer (score 5):

I'll get the conversation started by saying I don't think there is a word for that (yet).

I think the reason for this is that, if you imagine a hierarchy of genre descriptors for some work (a novel, for example), words like:

- "comedy"
- "tragedy"
- "drama"

Are "higher level", or less specific, descriptors of the work, whereas words like:

- "horror"
- "crime"
- "western"

Are "lower level", or more specific, and these ones don't have their own single word to describe someone who makes them.